# Greater than in SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a hard time figuring out a greater than in a SQL statement.

Here's my code:

```
select one, two, three from orders
where case when @orderid > 0 then orders.orderid = @orderid end
```

---

@orderid is parameter passed to the stored procedure. The idea is that if a valid (> 0) orderid is passed, then use that as the filter in the where clause, otherwise don't use it all.

Comment: What is the datatype orderid?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Guffa has the right answer, but the way you'd do this using the CASE trick (which does occasionally come in handy) is this:

```
--If order ID is greater than 0, use it for selection
--otherwise return all of the orders.
select one, two, three
from orders
where orders.orderid = CASE
    WHEN @orderid > 0 then @orderid
    ELSE orders.orderid
END
```

The CASE always has to return something, so if you want to "disable" a statement in your WHERE clause conditionally and can't use OR, you can just set the thing equal to itself and that should always be true (except when comparing nulls).

Edit: I should also say that on queries like this where the number of rows that can be returned could vary tremendously (one row versus the whole table), using the OPTION (RECOMPILE) hint may help performance a great deal in the single row case.

Comment: +1 for case solution and also noting it does not work with NULL

Answer (score 4):

NYCDotnet answer, like the rest of the answers here works, but they may not be [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

To make this non-SARGable query..

```
select one, two three from orders
where 
     case 
     when @orderid > 0 then orders.orderid  
     else 0
     end = @orderid
```

..SARGable, do this instead:

```
select one, two three from orders
where 
     @orderid > 0 and orders.orderid = @orderid

     or not (@orderid > 0)
```

If @orderid will not ever become negative, just make the solution simpler:

```
select one, two three from orders
where 
     @orderid > 0 and orders.orderid = @orderid

     or @orderid = 0
```

Or better yet, i.e. if @orderid will not become negative:

```
select one, two three from orders
where 
     @orderid = 0

     or orders.orderid = @orderid
```

Comment: You beat me to it - I was working in SSMS to come up with a better version since the solution I offered was causing clustered index scans.  Although I think your WHERE clauses aren't quite complete?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `CASE` here.  Same logic, re-arranged a little:

```
select one, two, three
from orders
where @orderid is null
   or @orderid <= 0
   or orders.orderid = @orderid
```

Comment: but how is this going to work for cases when orderid = 0? The table has orders with orderid > 0, which means that it will not return anything if an orderid is not passed. What I want is that if an orderid is not passed, then it shouldn't use that condition at all (i.e. return all rows).

Comment: It will work because of the `OR`. If you pass `0` or a negative `@orderid`, the condition will be true and all rows will  will be returned. You may want to add `OR @order_id IS NULL` if you want the same to happen when NULL is passed.

Comment: I think the null check was was was giving the incorrect results. Added to answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a condition as a value in the `case` expression.

You can just use the `or` operator to make the condition unused for invalid values:

```
select one, two, three from orders
where @orderid <= 0 or orders.orderid = @orderid
```

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work. See comment above on @dana's comment.

Comment: @IIS7Rewrite: Yes, it does work. I even tested it now to be absolutely 100% sure. If the condition before `or` is true, then whatever the condition after it evaluates to, the entire expression is true. So when you pass an invalid `@orderid` it will return all rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF @orderid < 0
   BEGIN
      RETURN
   END

  SELECT one, two, three 
  FROM orders 
  WHERE orders.orderid = @orderid
```

In fact since the id is an int and if its an identity column it will always be greater than zero so you do not really even need to bother checking if the @orderid is greater than zero.  That being said the above code will keep the query from running with an invalid order id.

You could also do it this way

```
SELECTone, two, three

FROM orders

WHERE orderid = @orderid AND @orderid > 0
```